# Apache Flink Is Windowing dependent on Timestamp assignment of EventTime Events

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to apache flink and am trying to understand how the concept of EventTime and Windowing is handled by flink.

So here's my scenario :

1. I have a program that runs as a thread and creates a files with 3
   fields every second of which the 3rd field is the timestamp.
2. **There is a little tweak though every 5 seconds I enter an older timestamp (t-5 you could say)  into the new file created.**
3. Now I run the stream processing job which reads the 3 fields above
   into a tuple.
4. Now I have defined the following code for watermarking and timestamp generation:

   ```
      WatermarkStrategy
     .<Tuple3<String, Integer, Long>>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
     .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.f2);
   ```
5. And then I use the following code for windowing the above and trying to get the aggregation :

   ```
    withTimestampsAndWatermarks
           .keyBy(0)
           .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(4000)))
           .reduce((x,y) -> new Tuple3<String, Integer, Long>(x.f0, x.f1 + y.f1,y.f2))
   ```
6. It is clear that I am trying to aggregate the numbers within each field.*(a little more context, the field(f2) that I am trying to aggregate are all 1s)*

Hence I have the following questions :

1. That is the window is just 4 seconds wide, and every fifth entry is
   an older timestamp, so I am expecting that the next window to have
   lesser counts. Is my understanding wrong here ?
2. If my understanding is right - I do not see any aggregation when running both programs in parallel, Is there something wrong with my code ?
3. **Another one that is bothering me is on what fields or on what parameters do the windows start time and end time really dependent ? Is it on the timestamp extracted from Events or is it from processing time**

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the `allowed lateness`: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html#allowed-lateness. If not configured, Flink will drop the late message. So for the next window, there will be less elements than previous window.

Window is assigned by the following calculation:

```
return timestamp - (timestamp - offset + windowSize) % windowSize
```

In your case, offset is 0(default). For event time window, the `timestamp` is the event time. For processing time window, the `timestamp` is the processing time from Flink operator. E.g. if windowSize=3, timestamp=122, then the element will be assigned to the window [120, 123).

Comment: An solution would be to increase the duration passed to the bounded-out-of-orderness strategy enough so that there aren't any late events.